# Try to create a dynamic range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to figure out on how I can accomplish this functionality using the **jQuery UI *range slider***. Basically the objective here is: if the user selects one of the options below(`Checkbox`) let say for example: from 50 pesos to 100 pesos or from 0 to 99 pesos, the slider will set the min handle to 50 pesos and max handle to 100 pesos.

http://s255.photobucket.com/user/testament1234/media/dynamicrangeslider_zpsb2ae70b4.jpg.html

Another example: if the user selects 100 to 1000 pesos the slider will set the min handle to 100 pesos and the max handle to 1000 pesos. Here is what I have started.

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    step:5,
    values: [ 0, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Php" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }

});
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
</script>
```

I'm lost here since I'm not good at backend coding.

**Updated** -

```
<script>
var price_value = jQuery("input.price_range").slider("option", "values");


jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( ("option", "values", [ 10, 25 ] ) {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    step:5,
    values: [ 0, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Php" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }

});
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/). You can change the min and max after the slider has been created using the `option()` method.

Comment: Please look at updated post. With regards to your comment i found something better using "option" but it seems it's not working properly